# Batch file - Error correction code failing

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to add error correction to a batch file. I am trying the following:

```
set "building="
set LANbuilding[1]=20
set LANbuilding[2]=21
set LANbuilding[3]=22
set LANbuilding[4]=23
set LANbuilding[5]=24
set LANbuilding[6]=25

:start 

set /p building="Enter the building:> "

for /l %%n in (1,1,6) do ( if %building% neq !LANbuilding[%%n]! 
echo invalid building, try again. 

goto :start ) 

else
```

After the "else" would continue the rest of the code.

So far, this produces no errors, but just closes the window.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You do not have delayed expansion enabled.  And that is the not the proper syntax for using an `IF ELSE`.  The syntax is clearly defined in the HELP for the `IF` command.  Open up a cmd prompt and type: `IF /?`

Comment: Your code does throw an error but you do not see it because the window closes.  First rule of debugging a batch file is run the batch file from a CMD prompt.

Comment: Are you running the application from command prompt? At the end of the code did you add `exit` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Set/P` when you are expecting selection from a known list of values.

```bat
Choice /C 123456 /N /M "Enter the building: "
Set "building=%ERRORLEVEL%"
```

**Edit**

You could even expand that to do something else, like output the variable and value appertaining to the selection:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "LANbuilding[1]=20"
Set "LANbuilding[2]=21"
Set "LANbuilding[3]=22"
Set "LANbuilding[4]=23"
Set "LANbuilding[5]=24"
Set "LANbuilding[6]=25"

Choice /C 123456 /N /M "Enter the building: "
Call Echo %%%%LANbuilding[%%ERRORLEVEL%%]%%%%=%%LANbuilding[%ERRORLEVEL%]%%
Timeout 5 /NoBreak>Nul
```

**Edit2**

If you're already using Delayed Expansion then you should be able to directly echo the value like this instead:

```bat
Set "LANbuilding[1]=20"
Set "LANbuilding[2]=21"
Set "LANbuilding[3]=22"
Set "LANbuilding[4]=23"
Set "LANbuilding[5]=24"
Set "LANbuilding[6]=25"

Choice /C 123456 /N /M "Enter the building: "
Echo the value associated with LANbuilding[%ERRORLEVEL%] is !LANbuilding[%ERRORLEVEL%]!
Timeout 5 /NoBreak>Nul
```

**Edit3**

This, which uses `Set/P` and a `For` loop, should allow the end user to select only buildings, 20-25:

```bat
Set "LANbuilding[1]=20"
Set "LANbuilding[2]=21"
Set "LANbuilding[3]=22"
Set "LANbuilding[4]=23"
Set "LANbuilding[5]=24"
Set "LANbuilding[6]=25"

:Start 
Set/P "building=Enter the building: "
Set "_="
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%A In ('Set LANbuilding[ 2^>Nul'
) Do If "%building%" Equ "%%B" Set "_=%%A"
If Not Defined _ Echo invalid building, try again.&GoTo Start
Rem rest of code here:
Echo=[%%building%%=%building%]
Timeout 5 /NoBreak>Nul
```

In the code, I also set a variable `%_%` to a LANBuilding[Number] which has the value matching `%building%` too!

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I should have mentioned, I am using Delayedexpansion. It's declared in an earlier portion of the file. I'm running the file from a command prompt, so I can see any errors. I'm getting "the syntax of the command is incorrect". I have looked at the help for IF. I still can't get this to work properly. I have the IF section enclosed in a DO loop, which is probably complicating it, but it needs to iterate if the condition is true.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but how would I accomplish this using the `for, do` scenario? I'm trying to understand them better.

Comment: In the case above, what are you wanting the end user to enter? An integer, **1**-**6**, relating to the LANBuilding[***i***] or a two digit number, **20**-**25** relating to the values of the LANBuilding variables. *It isn't clear from the instruction or the question body*.

Comment: The correct buildings are 20 through 25. The 1-6 are just the elements that the loop cycles through checking each assigned value. The user should enter a correct building, like 22, otherwise it should echo the error, and goto the start of the loop.

Comment: Thanks much for your input.

That seems to be working correctly, although I haven't tested it with the rest of the code yet.

Wouldn't `tokens=1*` imply 1,2 and anything after? shouldn't it only accept 1 and 2, since the valid buildings are only two characters?

And why have a = as a delimiter?